# calling cuda c kernel from fortran 90

Tags: cuda, fortran90

I am planning to call a typical matrix multiply CUDA C kernel from a fortran program. I am referring the following link http://www-irma.u-strasbg.fr/irmawiki/index.php/Call_CUDA_from_Fortran . I would be glad if any resources is available on this. I intend to avoid PGI Cuda Fortran as I am not possessing the compiler. In the link above I cannot make out what should be the CUDA.F90 file. I assume the last code given in the link is that of main.F90. Kindly help.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you need to re-read the very first line of that page you linked to. Those instructions are relying on a set of external ISO C bindings for the CUDA API. That is where the `CUDA.F90` file you are asking about comes from. You will need to download and build the FortCUDA bindings to use the instructions on that wiki page.

Edited to add that given your last question was about compilation in Nsight Visual Studio Edition, it would seem that you are running on a Windows platform. You should know that you can't use gcc to build CUDA applications on Windows platforms. The supplied CUDA libraries will only work with either the Microsoft toolchain or (possibly) Intel's compilers in certain cases.

Comment: Many thanks. Yes, I completely missed the external C bindings mentioned at the beginning. I did not go through the actually meanings of these ISO C bindings. In fact I relied on the link [here](http://www.computationalmathematics.org/topics/files/calling_cuda_from_fortran.html) and was able successfully call the CUDA C kernel. The content of makefile is as under:Test: fortest.f95 cudatest.o
    optirun gfortran -L /usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart fortest.f95   cudatest.o
    cudatest.o: cudatest.cu 
    optirun nvcc -c cudatest.cu'  optirun command may be ignored if not using bumblebee.

Comment: Regarding the Nsight VS Edition, I was trying for some other laptop. I exclusively work on Linux environment. By the way I was able to call a CUDA C kernel as mentioned in my last comment. I have not used ISO C bindings. Am I missing something in terms of functionality?